# Is it correct to refer to OSGi as a Dependency Injection mechanism?

Tags: terminology

I read the Wikipedia articles on both, and both are not mentioned together. Also, the purpose of OSGi is not Dependency Injection. Yet, what an OSGi container like Felix does matches the description for DI.

Answer (score 2):

OSGi is conceptually related to Dependency Injection, both are about [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). A form of Dependency Injection can be achieved in OSGi via its [Declarative Services specification](http://www.osgi.org/Release4/Download), as explained in:

- Neil Bartlett's [Getting Started with OSGi: Declarative Services and Dependencies](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t97690.rhtml)<sup>*</sup>,
- Kai Tödter's blog post [Eclipse 4.0: Dependency Injection and OSGi Declarative Services](http://www.toedter.com/blog/?p=222),
- and this [OSGi DevCon Europe presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/fmeschbe/declarative-services-dependency-injection-osgi-style).

You can also achieve DI in OSGi via [peaberry](http://code.google.com/p/peaberry/), an extension library for [Google-Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) that supports dependency injection of dynamic services and provides OSGi integration out of the box.

<sub>* Worth noting that the article is part of a series listed in OSGi Alliance's [basic education on OSGi technology](http://www.osgi.org/Links/BasicEducation) page.</sub>